# Sphinx Error: (type='index') already exists

Tags: sphinx

I have my sphinx configuration broken out into 3 files as I have several different indexes that each use common files.

So I have a master sphinx.com that defines paths for where source and index are

Then each index has a source file (sql select, fields) and an index file with all the wordform paths and any rules for that specific index of data.

So I've been making changes to one of the indexes but all of a sudden am getting this error:

```
ERROR: section 'MyIndex_0' (type='index') already exists in /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf line 17863 col 19
```

Yet I did not touch the sphinx.conf file.

Update: As a test I found an old version of the index file I am trying to rotate so I still get the error. So it is not changes I made to this file (once in a while when making changes I get an error which is always due to some type or another).

Can some file have gotten corrupted?

I did stop and start sphinx to no avail.

Comment: pls provide your /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf and if it's a dynamic config - the compiled version too

Comment: @ManticoreSearch I can do the sphinx.conf, the dynamics dont seem to matter as anyone I tried to rotate even old ones that work(ed) throw the same error. Is it possible some files is missing in var?

Comment: w/o the config I can't say for sure what the problem is

Comment: @ManticoreSearch I'm saying I don't thingk it is the various configs. None of them rotate now and I only modified one of them. The sphinx.conf has not been modified in over a year. I did at some point delete some temp files in the var/data and wonder if i got rid of something critical.

Is there a way to rebuild all those files other then stop/start?

Comment: @ManticoreSearch I have a feeling not config, I checked the log and it looks like an issue that occurs sometiems with Linux? caught SIGHUP (seamless=1, in queue=1) I am going to start a new question and close this thank you.